# Can you describe vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$ without a basis?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

For example, you can describe a vector in $M_{m \times n}(\mathbb{F})$ in terms of a coordinate vector of the standard basis or as the vector (matrix) itself. However, for something like $\mathbb{R}^n$, when you describe any given vector, if no basis is specified, does that not mean that it is simply in terms of a standard basis?

How would you describe an arbitrary $v \in \mathbb{R}^3$ for example? I think that if you write something like:

$$w =\begin{bmatrix}
 1 \\
 1 \\
 0 
\end{bmatrix} \in \mathbb{R}^3$$

is this not the same as $[w]_B$, where $B$ is the standard basis?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm in an introductory linear algebra class, but this came into my mind, where it seems like the vector space of $\mathbb{F}^n$ has vectors $v$ described as synonymous with $[v]_B$, whereas, for something like matrices, the distinction is more important.

Answer (score 3):

It is not really the same since $w\in \mathbb{R}^3$ (that is, $w$ is a vector) and $\left[w\right]_B \in F^{3 \times 1}$ (that is, $\left[w\right]_B$ is a matrix-- a matrix which represents $w$ in the standard basis, but a matrix nonetheless).

The notion of basis only makes sense after a vector space is defined. So vectors exist independent of the basis, but the *representation* of those vectors depends on the basis chosen.

Answer (score 3):

What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ in the first place? The usual defintion is that it is the set of all order triples with entries from $\mathbb{R}$. Each ordered triple might be written $(a,b,c)$ or $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ if you prefer.

This is all established well before you think about properties that would let you write $$\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}=a\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}+b\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix}+c\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}$$ etc. That is, well before you think of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as a vector space with vector space properties.

After you have defined $\mathbb{R}^3$ this way, then you can define what it means to add two such things together and how that creates a new such thing. And you can define what it might mean to multiply such a thing by a real scalar and get a new such thing. And what it means to negate such a thing to get a new such thing. And now that you have these actions defined, you can check that it turns out $\mathbb{R}^3$ (the set of triples) together with these actions makes a vector space. And at that point you could start calling $(a,b,c)$ or $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ a vector. (And maybe your definition of $\mathbb{R}^3$ was all of this in the first place: the collection of triples together with addition, negation, and scalar multiplication.)

So we could be calling these things vectors, but we could still be at a point where the notion of a basis is not with us yet.

---

If the concept of a basis is understood, and with the convention that the standard basis is $\{\vec{e}_1,\vec{e}_2,\vec{e}_3\}=\left\{\begin{bmatrix}1\\0\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\1\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\1\end{bmatrix}\right\}$, then when you see something like $\begin{bmatrix}a\\b\\c\end{bmatrix}$ without any reason to thing it is a coordinate vector wrt some other basis, then it's true you could/should think of it as the coordinate vector wrt that standard basis.

Comment: *What is your definition of $\mathbb{R}^3$*, sometimes it is helpful to state the obvious. So (+1)